# jQuery - order DIVs depending on an extracted number of a classname

Tags: jquery

I have a list of DIVs, like this :

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="classA classB SORT-4.2"><div>4</div></div>
    <div class="classA SORT-3.3"><div>3</div></div>
    <div class="classC classD classE SORT-5.1"><div>5</div></div>
    <div class="classB classC SORT-1.5"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="classA class B class C SORT-2.4"><div>2</div></div>
</div>
```

and I want to sort them, using jQuery

Server-side, I can define the wanted order, and include this order in the class names :

SORT-**4.2**

I want to be able to call either the first order (in my example this DIV will be in the 4th position), or the second order (it will be in the 2nd position) : that explains the "4.2"

So if I call `OrderDIV(1)` I will have this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and if I call `OrderDIV(2)` I will have this :

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

(I will need to add more orders, like : SORT-4.2.5.6.2)

As you can see DIVs can have multiple classes, only the pattern `SORT-` defines the class used to sort

Thank you VERY MUCH for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that accepts the divs and the order number (1,2,etc).

Convert the divs from a jQuery object to an Array of DOM elements.

Use a regular expression to extract the proper information from the className and overwrite the Array so it looks like:

```
arr[0] = {num:4, el:/* the element */}
arr[1] = {num:2, el:/* the element */}
arr[2] = {num:3, el:/* the element */}
```

Then sort on `a.num` and `b.num`.

Finally iterate the array, appending each element.

```
function sort( divs, order ) {
    var arr = divs.toArray(),
        len = arr.length,
        parent = divs.parent(),
        i = 0;

    while( i < len ) {
        var num = arr[ i ].className.match(/(?:SORT-([\d.]+))/)[1].split('.');
        arr[ i ] = {num:num[ order - 1 ],el:arr[ i ]};
        i++;
    }
    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.num - b.num;
    });
    i = 0;
    while( i < len ) {
        parent.append( arr[i].el );
        i++;
    }
}
```

Result is:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/10/

```
sort( $('#list > div'), 3 ); // 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Seems perfect, I don't understand why I can't test your code in my real project (more complicated than the example here)

Comment: Perhaps the original DOM selection? Could you post a sample of your original code? And are the divs being sorted actual siblings, or are they more like cousins?

Comment: It's quite weird, my original code works on jsfiddle, but not on my computer... How can I launch the function? Is it correct : `<a href="#" onclick="sort( $('#list > div'), 1 );">SORT!</a>`

Comment: @jrm: Yes, that's correct *as long as* you've defined the `sort()` function in global namespace. In other words, make sure it's not wrapped in another function like jQuery's `.ready()`. Can you post a jsFiddle of your code?

Comment: @patrick dw : It works perfectly on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/2/) but not on my computer...

Comment: @jrm: OnDomReady effectively wraps the code like you would with jQuery's `.ready()`. I'll take a look at your example.

Comment: @jrm:...In the jsFiddle, we're calling your `sort()` function when the page loads. If you're calling it from a link, you need to make sure your `sort()` function is defined globally. Take it out of any other function, or assign it explicitly to `window`, as in `window.sort( divs, order ) { //and so on...`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/3/ Here I removed "OnDomReady", and created a link to sort the items. It works. If you select "OnDomReady" and click "Run" it will stop working.

Comment: @jrm: My pleasure. Glad it worked out. :o) If you really really like this answer, you can click the "up-arrow" a couple images above the checkmark to give it an up-vote. ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw: patrick, how can I adapt the code to accept more than 2 different orders? (I want to be able to use 5 orders, and to define them with a class like "SORT-2.4.8.1.2") - THANK YOU :)

Comment: @patrick dw: your regex (I also try `SORT-(\d+)(\.(\d+))*`) seems to fail (but `SORT-(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)` works)

Comment: @jrm: Yeah, I sort of messed up the regex. Didn't need to be quite so complex. Now it's simpler. With the new one, also needed to decrement the `order` number passed in. Give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/6/

Comment: @patrick dw: Thank you for your help, seems better but I really need to keep the "SORT-" part, or the new regex may include some other `d+` being in other classnames of the concerned divs

Comment: @patrick dw: and `match(/SORT-(\d+)/g);` does not seem to work properly

Comment: @jrm: Ah yes. [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/TsArJ/10/). I went back closer to the original, but took some of the work out of the regex. `var num = arr[ i ].className.match(/(?:SORT-([\d.]+))/)[1].split('.');` Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some like this:

```
$(function(){
    function sortDIV(){
        var divs=$("div[class*=SORT]").clone();
        divs.sort(function(pDiv,fDiv){
            var pNumber=parseInt($(pDiv).attr("class").match(/SORT-(.*)/)[1].replace(".",""));
            var fNumber=parseInt($(fDiv).attr("class").match(/SORT-(.*)/)[1].replace(".",""));
            return pNumber<fNumber;
        })
        var parent=$($("div[class*=SORT]")[0]).parent();
        parent.empty();
        divs.each(function(index,div){
                $(div).appendTo(parent);
        })
    }
    sortDIV();
})
```

more info: http://jsfiddle.net/apvjN/20/

Comment: seems great! Is is possible to add the possibility to select if I want to sort with the first digit SORT-**4**.2 or the second digit SORT-4.**2** ?

Comment: and your script seems to order in the wrong way, (5 first, and 1 last), is it possible to reverse the result?